# Creating file from shell input in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a file from shell input. That is, I want to run some command, then type the desired contents of my file, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and have it create my file with the contents I typed in.

What would be the command for that?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No! I'm stuck for an hour at work because of this! But I'm happy to know it's easy enough to be considered homework!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `cat` command to concatenate STDIN to the file like so: `cat >> out.txt` (or to blow away the already existing file, don't append `cat > out.txt`) then type when done press `ctl+d` to terminate when you are done.